# How to Fix the height of RecyclerView in XML or from code in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin-android-extensions

I have tried the below code but all the time its giving me the recyclerview as full screen any idea how to solve this.

Note i have only two rows/items in my `recyclerview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textfield"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </EditText>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what are you trying to achieve. So that we can help you. Do you want Editext below the recycler view?

Comment: Yes i want the edit textfiled below the recyclerview

Comment: check your layout/recyclerview_item, I have a feeling that you set the height of that layout to match_parent.

Comment: @JustinHilton Please upvote or mark the answer as correct if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes you can do it with constraint layout here is the code you can follow
```

Note: Please do `clean` & `Rebuild Project` to reflect the correct UI changes i have noticed in Android Studio 3.5+ sometimes the UI doesn't reflect.

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textfield"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textfield"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerview1" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textfield"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerview_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </EditText>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`recyclerview_item` should use `wrap_content` as `layout_height`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> <!--Should be wrap_content-->

    <!--Here list item content-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:
[image]

You can also achieve this by simply use `LinearLayout` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textfield"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp">

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to implement this by using `relativelayout`.
Just replace your code with this.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item"
        android:layout_above="@id/textfield"//Recyclerview will take above area.
       />
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textfield"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textfield"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textfield"
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerview1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.